# Matplotlib - Formatting two plots on the same figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot some data but I'm getting stuck on plotting 2 plots on same figure. It looks like this:

[image]

The code is:

```
import re
import sqlite3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import datetime as dt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

...

for company in companies:
    cursor.execute("select distinct url from t_surv_data where company = ? order by product_type", (company,))
    urls = [r[0] for r in cursor.fetchall()]

    for idx, url in enumerate(urls):              
    cursor.execute("select price, timestamp from t_surv_data where url = ? order by timestamp", (url,))
    data = [[r[0], r[1]] for r in cursor.fetchall()]
    price, date = zip(*data)                
    date = [dt.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for d in date]

    f = plt.figure('''figsize=(3, 2)''')

    ax = f.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(date, price) # x, y
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%d\n%h\n%Y'))
    #ax.set_ylim(ymin=0) # If I use this a break the plot

    ax2 = f.add_subplot(211)
    ax2.scatter(date, [1,1,-1])
    ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%d\n%h\n%Y'))
    #ax2.set_ylim(ymin=-1, ymax=1) # If I use this a break the plot

    plt.savefig('plt/foo' + str(idx) + '.png')
    plt.close()
```

How can I solve this questions:

1 - The plots looks like they are one above the other. How can I format this with a visual to look like independent plots on the same figure.

2 -  I'm using this line of code to both plots "ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%d\n%h\n%Y'))" but there is no sync in the dates. The dates should be equal in the two plots.

Some one can give me a clue on this questions?

Best Regards,

Comment: First, for adding subplots, the format is `add_subplot(N_rows, N_cols, N_plot)`. So your subplots should be `211` and `212`, not `111` and `211`.

Comment: Second, the `DateFormatter` only takes the xticks from the plot and reformats them; it only formats the existing ticks. To get the same dates on the two x-axes, you could either do `ax.set_xlim(start, end)` for both, or have the two subplots `share_x`. Check out [this demo page](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html)

Answer (score 3):

You are not using `add_subplot` correctly:

```
ax = f.add_subplot(2,1,1)
ax2 = f.add_subplot(2,1,2)
```

The first number indicates the number of rows, the second the number of columns and the third the index of the plot.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the plots to share the x axis (that is the axis with dates), you have to specify the `sharex` property.

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)
ax1.plot(...)
ax2.scatter(...)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%d\n%h\n%Y'))
```

You only have to set the major formatter once since they share the x axis.

Comment: As a side note you can unpack the `AxesSubplot` instances directly : `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(...`.

Comment: Thank you Viktor and nordev. This is also correct. I don't know on who to check as correct. Both are correct.